# create jquery dialog from javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an javascript / jquery object that renders html - a div with a table and an edit button, and a jquery popup dialog.

I have always called the jquery dialog in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Is it possible to create the dialog when I create the object.

in other words

```
object = new newTable('div_id');
```

and in the object there is

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "#" + this.popup_id ).dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: 
            {
                "Next": function() 
                {
                    process_account_wizard('next');


                },
                "Skip": function() 
                {
                    process_account_wizard('skip');


                },
                Cancel: function() 
                {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() 
            {
            },

        });

});
```

so when the document is ready the objects sets up the dialog.

An alternate question is can I automatically run initialization code for an object once the page is loaded?

Edit: I have confirmed I can first create the object then run `object.init()` in the document ready function and the dialog works correctly. Trying to avoid this an make the object do it automatically.

I might have to edit this question a few times to figure out how to ask it. Thanks for your help

Comment: i'm really confused on what is being asked here

Comment: working on making it more clear

Comment: So you are looking to basically have the dialog initialized when the constructor fires on a new object instance?

Comment: yes, the dialog should be hidden and ready to popup when I create the object.The object is created before the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to convert your `object` variable (though I'd want to think up a more appropriate name than "object") and initialise the dialog against that.

So, within whatever function calls `object = new newTable('div_id');` paste your dialog initialisation from your question replacing -

```
$( "#" + this.popup_id ).dialog(
```

with

```
$(object).dialog(
```

Comment: Thanks John, I did re-format this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440042/jquery-ui-dialog-shows-on-page-instead-of-popup after your answer from a previous question. Using this solution gives me a new set of errors - the popup works however the requested popup div contents are on the page, not the popup.