# Setup jqueryui before element is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

In creating a table cells with very cool options I need to take two steps. First I create the table cell as a DOM object in javascript with all the 'normal' functionality, like is it a checkbox, a select, an input, a link, etc. 
Then I need to put the table on the page to do the next step, which I consider advanced functionality like jqueryui's autocomplete and date select. It is awesome to have these drop downs for the user.

I do have this working, however, I do need to make two calls. The first to createTableCell, then I render, then I need to make another call to postRenderTableFunctions to get the autocomplete functionality working. So the question is, why the second call, what is it about jqueryui that will not work on the first call. You can see the commented section under input creation where I tried to get the autocomplete working.

```
function createTableCell(name, td_def)
{           
        var cell=document.createElement('td');
        if(td_def['type'] == 'date')
        {
            var element = document.createElement('input');
            element.name = name;
            element.id = name;              
            cell.appendChild(element);

            $('#' + element.id).datepicker(                 
            {
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function () 
                {
                    $(this).focus();
                },
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) 
                {
                    $(this).select();
                }
            });

        }
        else if(td_def['type'] == 'checkbox')
        {


            element = document.createElement('input');
            element.type = 'checkbox';
            element.name = name;
            element.id = name;
            /*if(this.tdo[r][td_def['db_field']]['data'] == 1)
            {
                element.checked = true;
            }*/
            cell.appendChild(element);      



        }
        else if (td_def['type'] == 'select')
        {
            element = document.createElement('select');
            element.name = name;
            element.id = name;
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = 'NULL';
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select..."));
            element.appendChild(option);
            for (var j in td_def['select_names'])
            {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = td_def['select_values'][j];
                option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(td_def['select_names'][j]));
                element.appendChild(option);
            }
            cell.appendChild(element);
        }
        else if (td_def['type'] == 'tree_select')
        {
            element = document.createElement('select');
            element.id = name;
            element.name = name;


            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = 'NULL';
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Select..."));
            element.appendChild(option);
            var level = 0;
            //console.log(td_def['select_array']);
            this.addNestedSelectOptions(element, td_def['select_array'], level);




            if (typeof td_def['properties'] !== 'undefined')
            {
                for (var index in td_def['properties'])
                {
                    eval('element.' + index + '= ' + td_def['properties'][index] + ';');

                }
            }
            cell.appendChild(element);
        }               
        else if (td_def['type'] == 'input')
        {
            element = document.createElement('input');
            element.type = 'text';
            element.id = name;
            element.name = name;
            cell.appendChild(element);
            /*      
            if(typeof td_def['autoComplete'] != 'undefined')
            {

                console.log('attempting Autocomplete');
                $( "#" + name ).autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) 
                    {
                     $.ajax(
                     {
                            url: td_def['autoComplete']['url'],
                            type: 'GET',
                            async: true,
                            data: 
                            {
                                ajax_request: td_def['autoComplete']['ajax_request'],
                                featureClass: "P",
                                style: "full",
                                maxRows: 12,
                                search_terms: request.term
                            },
                            success: function( data ) 
                            {
                                console.log(data);
                                parsed_autocomplete_data = parseJSONdata(data);
                                response( parsed_autocomplete_data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    search: function() 
                    {
                        // custom minLength
                        var term = this.value;
                        //console.log(term);
                        if(typeof td_def['minLength'] != 'undefined')
                        {
                            var minL =   td_def['minLength'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var minL =  1;
                        }
                        if ( term.length < minL ) 
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    focus: function() 
                    {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                        return false;
                    },
                    open: function(event, ui)
                    {
                        var dialog = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog');
                        if(dialog.length > 0){
                            $('.ui-autocomplete.ui-front').zIndex(dialog.zIndex()+1);
                        }
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) 
                    {
                        selected_autocomplete_index = $.inArray(ui.item.value, parsed_autocomplete_data);
                    }
                });
            }
            */

        }
        else if (td_def['type'] == 'textarea')
        {
            element = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
            element.id = name;
            element.name = name;
            cell.appendChild(element);

        }
        else if (td_def['type'] == 'td')
        {

            cell.innerHTML = 'TBD';
            cell.name = name;
            cell.id = name; 

        }
        else
        {
            alert(td_def['type'] + ' have not coded that.....');
        }

        return cell;

        function addNestedSelectOptions(element, category_array, level)
        {
            for (var key in category_array)
            {
                option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = key;
                name = category_array[key]['name'];


                for(i=0;i<level;i++)
                {
                    name = "\u00A0" + name;
                    name =  "\u00A0" + name;
                }
                option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
                element.appendChild(option);
                if(!$.isEmptyObject(category_array[key]['children']))
                {
                    addNestedSelectOptions(element, category_array[key]['children'], level+1);
                }
            }
        }

}
//this function needs to be called separately.
function postRenderTableFunctions(table_div_id, table_def)
{
    //extra jquery functionality -- needs to go after stuff is rendered
    for(var i=0;i<table_def.length;i++)
    {
        if(typeof table_def[i]['autoComplete'] != 'undefined')
        {
            var id = table_div_id + '_' + table_def[i]['db_field'];
            console.log(id);
            //is the auto complete open?
            /*$("#" + id ).bind('autocompleteopen', function(event, ui) 
            {
                $(this).data('is_open',true);
            });

            $("#" + id ).bind('autocompleteclose', function(event, ui) 
            {
                $(this).data('is_open',false);
            });*/   
            /*$( "#" + id ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) 
            {
                //what is this for ?
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data('is_open') ) 
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER  && !$(this).data('is_open')) 
                {
                    //do what?
                }
            });*/
            var i2 = i;
            var me = table_def;
            $( "#" + id ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) 
                {
                 $.ajax(
                 {
                        url: me[i2]['autoComplete']['url'],
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: true,
                        data: 
                        {
                            ajax_request: me[i2]['autoComplete']['ajax_request'],
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            search_terms: request.term
                        },
                        success: function( data ) 
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            parsed_autocomplete_data = parseJSONdata(data);
                            response( parsed_autocomplete_data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                search: function() 
                {
                    // custom minLength
                    var term = this.value;
                    //console.log(term);
                    if(typeof table_def[i2]['minLength'] != 'undefined')
                    {
                        var minL =   table_def[i2]['minLength'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var minL =  1;
                    }
                    if ( term.length < minL ) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                focus: function() 
                {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                open: function(event, ui)
                {
                    var dialog = $(this).closest('.ui-dialog');
                    if(dialog.length > 0){
                        $('.ui-autocomplete.ui-front').zIndex(dialog.zIndex()+1);
                    }
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                    selected_autocomplete_index = $.inArray(ui.item.value, parsed_autocomplete_data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect i may work if you replace `$( "#" + name ).autocomplete({` with `$(element).autocomplete({` though I don't currently have means to test it.

Comment: John it appears that you are correct. Can you help me understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original comment to your question -

I suspect i may work if you replace

```
$( "#" + name ).autocomplete({
```

with

```
$(element).autocomplete({
```

though I don't currently have means to test it.

My response -

Basically using `$("#name")` looks for an element with the ID `name` in the DOM.  When you are running your code `element` has not been added to the DOM yet so the autocomplete cannot be attached to to your element.

Surrounding `element` with `$()` converts it to a jQuery variable which you can attach the autocomplete to before it is added to the DOM.

Comment: John C - I think this question of mine has the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973925/create-jquery-dialog-from-javascript-object - I have the div element so let me see if I can get the dialog to work without running a second init call