# JQuery UI Dialog shows on page instead of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, popup

I have a jqueryUI dialog popup that is showing on the page... and popping up when requested. Some odd functionality. Anything within the div will show on the page, and the popup will work however be without the contents on the div. I am trying to create the popup before the document is ready. Here is the code that my object is running, again before document ready.

```
    var edit_div=document.createElement('div');                 
    var me = this;
    $(edit_div).dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: 
            {
                "Submit": function() 
                {
                    me.submitForm();
                },
                Cancel: function() 
                {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() 
            {
            },

        });
```

The popup works correctly if I move the dialog creation code to a separate function and call that when the document is ready like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   mfg_table.init();
}
```

And the init code to create the dialog

```
   this.init = function()
    {
        //alert('initing');
        var me = this;
        $('#' +this.table_id + this.edit_table_name).dialog(
            {
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 600,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: 
                {
                    "Submit": function() 
                    {
                        me.submitForm();
                    },
                    Cancel: function() 
                    {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                close: function() 
                {
                },

            });
    }
```

So why can't I create the dialog on the DOM object before rendering of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your script is being called before your jquery.js files are being loaded by the browser?

Document.ready waits until the page is fully loaded before running your code. The fact that it isn't working correctly without it, implies that the necessary resources aren't being loaded before you try to run your script.

You may want to try to move your inline script to the very end of your html file, particularly after all your .js and plugin files have been referenced.

I wish I could be more specific, but it's hard to see whats going on without more of the code or a live example.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh man loading javascript is a pain. I load jquery inline in the head, first, followed by jqueryui followed by my main library. These are loaded the old-school way. ex: $html .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . JQUERY_VERSION .'"></script>'.newline();
 $html .='<script type="text/javascript" src="' . JQUERY_UI_VERSION.'"></script>'.newline();
 $html .= '<script src="' . JAVASCRIPT_LIBRARY .'"></script>'.newline(); Then I load the script file that creates the table objects in the body. Then I instantiate the object in my javascript specific for the page in the body.

Comment: So I don't believe that is the reason, however certainly have run into this before.